# Retrieve line spacing in TextView - Android

Tags: android, textview, format

How can I retrieve the line spacing values (as currently applied to a piece of text) in a `TextView`? In API 16 and above, the appropriate functions to call would be `getLineSpacingExtra()` and `getLineSpacingMultiplier()`. What are the appropriate functions for API version less than 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of `TextView` as given [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/TextView.java) shows that `getLineHeight` returns an `integer` for the line height whose 'formula' is given as:

`lineHeight =  FastMath.round(mTextPaint.getFontMetricsInt(null) * mSpacingMult
                          + mSpacingAdd);`

`mSpacingMult` and `mSpacingAdd` can be set with `setLineSpacing(float mult, float add)`. Both these functions are available since API Level 1.